# Nginx: write rule for query param having values 1,2,3,4

Tags: nginx

I am trying to write nginx rule for URL which has query param ending with 1,2,3,4.

```
location ^~ /membership/plans {
 if ($request_uri ~* "mem_redirect_flow=1"){
     set $memcheck 1;
 }
 if ($request_uri ~* "mem_redirect_flow=2"){
     set $memcheck 1;
 }
 if ($request_uri ~* "mem_redirect_flow=3"){
     set $memcheck 1;
 }
 if ($request_uri ~* "mem_redirect_flow=4"){
     set $memcheck 1;
 }
  .....
}
```

i want a way whether i can write these if statement in single line

Comment: As it's already a regular expression, try: `"mem_redirect_flow=[1-4]"`

Comment: @RichardSmith i tried this regex but it didn't work (it worked for 11, 111, and so on)

Comment: You need to include the expected characters before and after the parameter: `"[?&]mem_redirect_flow=[1-4](&|$)"`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can use the $arg_*name* variable to access query parameters parsed out of the request URI, then the pattern match is much simpler when it is just on the value:

```
location ^~ /membership/plans {
 if ($arg_mem_redirect_flow ~ ^[1-4]$) {
     set $memcheck 1;
 }
}
```

Alternatively, you can avoid using an `if` by doing this in a `map`:

```
map $arg_mem_redirect_flow $memcheck {
  ~^[1-4]$ 1;
  default  0;
}
```

Note that this will need to be declared outside of your `server` block.